# Using popup windows in Visual Studio C# and ASP.NET - quick learning

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Whenever the "Reserve" button is clicked in my web application (ASP.NET with C#, Visual Studio), a small window should pop up containing detailed options to choose from (drop down lists with values, comboboxes, etc), with a "Next" link, and "Finish", in the end. Changing the values in these controls should update tables I have in the database (Microsoft Sql Server).

Could you point me towards a detailed and useful resource/example of this? I am already using a book for inspiration (Cristian Darie) written in the form of steps / explanations, but scenarios as just described are not included. What should I be looking for? "Using Pop up windows with Visual Studio"? Is what I described known as a popup window?

I don't know JavaScript, is that needed here? Been practising lately a lot with classes, methods, stored procedures, masters, user control type files, handling db tables through Visual Studio classes and methods, etc but still new to these (a month old basically). Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this. The important point to make is that the window you pop up is just an ASPX page so the fact that it's a pop-up doesn't really change the fact that you still need to write an ASPX page or UserControl to process the data inputs and submit the changes to the database, as I'm sure your book will cover. Disassociate the fact that it's a popup with what the control in the popup window is doing.

Comment: There are many ways of doing it, but please follow one bit of advice: keep it consistent throughout your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not necessary to use JavaScript, but if you want anything a bit more fancy than just a regular popup window, javascript will be a good friend to you. As I see it it's basically four main ways of doing it:

1

Create a new ASPX file with the "details", send a querystring to the url of the details view in order to connect the popup with the data from the main window. a key to this is the "target" property of the html "a" tag. For example:

> ```
> <a href="mynewwindow.aspx?i=3" target="_NEW">Details</a>
> ```

2

Create a popup window with some custom properties (i.e toolbars window size of popup etc) using regular javascript. Look for window.open in javascript.

Example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open("details.aspx?i=3","mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");">Details</a>
```

3

Using jQuery to open the popup in a modal dialog fashion using a lightbox. For this alternative I don't have any example, but google jQuery lightbox, there are heaps of them. Use that with an AJAX-call and achieve your goals.

4

And at last, use ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit (look here: 
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx) Download and install, use the ModalPopupExtender (tutorial here: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_ModalPopup.ashx) from the toolkit, in which case you design your "details" view in a <asp:Panel> control and then using CSS and the ModalPopupExtender to display and hide the details, the looks will be like the lightbox but you don't have to create a separate ASPX page for this option, but you can use the same ASPX.

I've worked alot with all four options, and i tend to like the 4th alternative the best, but we all have our own taste.

Good luck, and feel free to ask away for more detailed information. :)

Comment: Thank you, JaggenSWE for presenting a few options to pick from. The most appealing to me seem the first 2 options. The few issues would be: 1. If I go with your option one, can a window be an ASPX type and still have the look and feel of a pop up window? Small, etc.

Comment: 2. Let's say I have some buttons, I will remember the caption of the few selected ones by the user, and will need to send that information to the main page when I close the popup, how would I do that? I understand it's really complex, that's why perhaps you know an already build up example in the 'net. Can be most simple, so I have a starting point. Thanks a lot. 3. How should I start learning JavaScript if it's so useful?

Answer (score 1):

let's take this step by step. In order to send that information, I think the
easiest way would be to store the parameters as session variables and then reload them
when the popup is closed, you can reload the parent window using the "onunload" event in
Javascript, for example

```
<body onunload="window.opener.location.reload(true);">
```

This would in
itself reload the parent window whenever the user closes the popup. IF you want it to close
when the user saves changes (and your session variables are set), use this code in order to reload
the parent window and close the popup. Put this code in the code behind, just before the
end of your method that saves the data:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript(this.GetType(),"close","<script language=javascript>window.opener.location.reload(true);self.close();</script>");
```

To learn javascript, have a look at codeproject.com, they have a lot of articles regarding
javascript (among other things), often with example code. :)

I made a quick example here: http://www.4shared.com/zip/LPtR1gbx/pop.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recomment using a `<div>` element rather than an actual new browser window.

It eliminates the need to pass the contextual information from the pop-up window back to the original window along with all the complexities involved with it (including things like the user inadvertently clicking off the pop-up window, clicking multiple times and thus bringing up multiple copies of the pop-up window, and so forth).

By using a `<div>` that "pops up", via controlled visibility through CSS or JavaScript, the entire context is kept to the same web page, making life so much easier overall.